# How to parse number with multiple possible thousandsseparators?

Tags: c#, .net

Culture nb-NO has " " (space) as thousands separator (numbergroupseparator, currencygroupseparator etc), but it's very common to also type "." (period).
Decimal separator is ",".

How can I assign multiple thousands separators?

Comment: Do you mean multiple thousands separators in the one number? Or be able to parse numbers that each may use one of many different thousands separators?

Comment: If I had to do this I would probably try to parse with both ways. I'm assuming, of course, that it's unlikely that one number would use both separators simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what the separator is or know a list, use [Int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) and pass in the different cultures representing the separators. For example:

```
using System.Globalization;

...

string number; // Contains number to parse
int parsedNumber;
List<CultureInfo> cultures = new List<CultureInfo>()
{
    Cultureinfo.InvariantCulture,
    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    ... // Insert other cultures here
};
CultureInfo matchingCulture = cultures.FirstOrDefault(cultureInfo =>
    Int.TryParse(number, out parsedNumber, 
        NumberStyles.AllowThousands, cultureInfo));
if(matchingCulture != null)
{
    // parsedNumber contains the parsed number and matchingCulture contains 
    // the culture that parsed it
}
```

If separators are not represented by different cultures, consider using a simple string.Replace() to replace a list of known separators with a single known one, such as a comma. Note that this may have issues, for example, where thousands separators are used with decimal points because some country's conventions conflict.

Comment: Thanks, the first option is not going to work in my case, but the replace is good enough. I suppose I can check if the culture's decimal separator is the same as what I'm trying to replace with...

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a built-in solution, you can always replace the possible unwanted characters such as `,` with empty string, then parse the number.

Comment: But since the comma and dot could either be the decimal separator or thousands separator depending on the culture then that would be a little dangerous. 1,234 could be one thousand, two hundred and thirty four, or one point two three four. How do you tell which is which in any given case?

Comment: well, how can the parser tell which one it is anyway?

Comment: You tell the parser the culture you are parsing. See CultureInfo class

Comment: i know about the CultureInfo class. what i'm telling doesn't conflict with the usage of CultureInfo. when you try to parse it with nb-NO culture, it will try the space as the seperator as it's the official one. but you've said that it's also common for people to write period too, so just replace any possible periods with empty string or a space character and it should work.